# What is the "common neighborhood" of a single vertex in a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

In the paper "[On finding bicliques in bipartite graphs: a novel algorithm and its application to the integration of diverse biological data types](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-15-110)" the authors propose an improvement to an algorithm, by sorting candidate vertices by "common neighborhood size" (page 8 at left).

What is the "common" neighborhood for a single vertex?

Comment: A "neighborhood" of a vertex is the set of vertices it is adjacent to, so "common neighborhood size" would most likely mean "vertices of the same degree."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two vertices $x$ and $y$, $N(x, y) = N(x) \cap N(y)$ is the *common neighbourhood* of those two vertices where the size would be denoted as $|N(x) \cap N(y)|$.

> What is "common" neighborhood for a single vertex?

It seems a bit superfluous to use the term "common neighbourhood" when referring to a single vertex since the neighbours that a vertex has in common with itself is all of its neighbours.

$$
N(x, x) = N(x) \cap N(x) = N(x) \tag{Idempotent law}
$$

I think the authors of the paper are primarily concerned with comparing distinct vertices in partition $V$. This is covered in section "Candidate selection" which describes why selecting candidates in non-decreasing order of common neighbourhood size might reduce the number of non-maximal subsets that the algorithm has to generate. So in *Figure 5* for graph $G_4$, they are sorting based on $|N(v_i, v_{j})|$, which in this example results in the algorithm not picking candidate vertex $v_1$ first.

[image]